# Unity3D - How to measure the height of a stack of objects?

Tags: c#, game-physics, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 2D block stacking game in Unity where you instantiate blocks from a x-axis translating spawner object. The problem I'm facing is when the stack gets too high and close to the spawner, I need to move the spawner and game camera up on the Y-axis.I'm measuring a stack of prefabs to get their height using Bounds so I know when to move my camera and spawner.   The problem I'm facing is when I call my GetMaxBounds function and Encapsulate the additional points it is not adding to my parentBounds variable. My parentBounds.max.y never increases. I'm new to programming and C#. Thanks in advance.

[image: Game view]

```
if  (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        Instantiate (fallingBrick, spawnPosObj.transform.position, Quaternion.identity, parentStack.transform);
        var parentBounds = GetMaxBounds (parentStack);
        Debug.Log (parentBounds.max.y);
    }

}

Bounds GetMaxBounds(GameObject g) {
    var b = new Bounds(g.transform.position, Vector3.zero);
    foreach (Renderer r in g.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>()) {
        b.Encapsulate(r.bounds);
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Just add the heights of indivual objects in the stack.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is they don't always stack evenly. The sometimes fall, rotate and end up in different heights.

Comment: Are you doing any checks if the blocks are stacked on the tower? If so you can go through every object that is successfully stacked and multiply by the height of a single block.

Comment: I am but they don't always stack the same way. Currently trying to determine if I can get the height of my parent stack object containing all the child block objects using the Bounds suggestion below.

Answer (score 2):

Keep a counter which will store how many objects in the stack are present on the screen, and increment it each time an item is added in your stack. Then, considering you saved the size of one item, you just have to multiply your size by the number of items present on the stack. Just compare this size with the current vertical size of your scene, and move your camera when your stack reaches for instance 80% of the vertical size of your screen.

When you do so, remember to reset the number of items, as you will probably move your camera up and most of the items that were in the lower level of your stack will be hidden. For instance, if you let only 3 cubes visible when moving your camera, just set back your number of items in the stack to 3.

As your problem seems to include objects that won't stack the same way, another solution is to use [Bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html). Imagining you are keeping a list of all the items in your stack, you can evaluate the bounds of each one of the objects that would be added in a parent object representing the stack, and evaluate the vertical size by encapsulating each child bounds. You can find an example in [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86863/calculating-the-bounding-box-of-a-game-object-based-on-its-children):

```
Bounds GetMaxBounds(GameObject stack) {
   var b = new Bounds(stack.transform.position, Vector3.zero);
   foreach (Renderer r in g.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>()) {
     b.Encapsulate(r.bounds);
   }
   return b;
}
```

And you can then evaluate the vertical size by substracting the `max` y value of the evaluated `Bounds` object to the `min` y value. So you could have something like:

```
float GetVerticalSize(GameObject stack) {
   var b = new Bounds(stack.transform.position, Vector3.zero);
   foreach (Renderer r in g.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>()) {
     b.Encapsulate(r.bounds);
   }

   float size = b.max.y - b.min.y;
   return size;
}
```

Again, if you are moving your camera up, make sure to only use this solution on the items which are actually shown on screen.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. The problem is the stack increments aren't always one block in height. Sometimes they fall and rotate so they end up jumbled on the platform below.  Is there a way to measure in this case? I could shrink the platform and make it so that blocks can only be stacked vertically one by one and use this method though.

Comment: If he is storing all the blocks successfully stacked he should still be able to multiple the size of a single block and the amount of successfully stacked blocks that didn't fall.

Comment: @Lewie I suggested another solution for your case.

Comment: @Isuka - Thank you. Using Bounds seems like the right solution for my case since objects don't always stack the same way. Currently working on implementing this recommendation.

Comment: @Isuka - I was able to Instantiate my blocks into a parent stack object. I added the code to the post. Can you show me the GetMaxBounds function implementation where I would evaluate the vertical size by subtracting the max y value of the returned object to the min y value to get the vertical size?